# Ошибка Cross-Origin Request Blocked в Firefox

Tags: yii2, rest, firefox, cors

Проблема следующая:
Есть api на yii2 и фронт на react js
Контроллер на yii2 настроен следующим образом

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::class,
            'except' => ['options'],
        ];

        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::class,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => [
                        'options'
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization'],
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Total-Count', 'X-Pagination-Page-Count', 'X-Pagination-Per-Page', 'X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ]
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

В chrome все работает, а в firefox запрос OPTIONS возвращает 500 ошибку

В консоли выводится ошибка "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at {my_url}. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).", в ответе от сервера нет Allow-Control-* заголовков

Для других методов заголовки приходят, не приходят именно для OPTIONS и именно в firefox

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему это может происходить и как это исправить?

На сервере nginx. Быть может nginx требует дополнительной настройки?

Answer (score 0):

Если запросы отправляете с localhost, то в Chrome, например он больше не поддерживается
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * doesn't match localhost"
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Comment: "В chrome все работает..." - цитата из вопроса

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос "почему это происходит"